# mutate values based on relative row position

Tags: r, dplyr

I am cleaning up some data imported from Excel. I am trying to create a column of values based on the position of a row in a data frame. Specifically, I am trying to assign a value to rows *between* two rows with specific character values using `mutate()` and `ifelse()`. Here is a very simplified example of the data I am working with:

```
     a        b    
[1,] "5"      "yes"
[2,] "6"      "no" 
[3,] "7"      "no" 
[4,] "2"      "yes"
[5,] "apple"  NA   
[6,] "4"      "yes"
[7,] "1"      "no" 
[8,] "banana" NA   
[9,] "6"      "yes"
[10,] "3"      "yes"
```

I want to create a `c` column that returns a character value of colors, where the rows between `"apple"` and `"banana"` (row numbers [6] and [7])are assigned a `c` column value of `"red"`, and all other rows are assigned a value of `"blue"`. Is there a way to do this? Please let me know if I can explain my problem more clearly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your data looks like it's a matrix instead of a data.frame, which you should fix if you plan on using dplyr. Once you get that sorted, you can use `cumsum` on each term (lagged if you don't want to count `apple` rows), subtract, and then use `ifelse` to convert `0` and `1` to `blue` and `red`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = '  a        b    
[1,] "5"      "yes"
[2,] "6"      "no" 
[3,] "7"      "no" 
[4,] "2"      "yes"
[5,] "apple"  NA   
[6,] "4"      "yes"
[7,] "1"      "no" 
[8,] "banana" NA   
[9,] "6"      "yes"
[10,] "3"      "yes"', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

rownames(df) <- NULL

df %>% 
    mutate(c = cumsum(lag(a, default = '') == 'apple') - cumsum(a == 'banana'),
           c = ifelse(as.logical(c), 'red', 'blue'))
#>         a    b    c
#> 1       5  yes blue
#> 2       6   no blue
#> 3       7   no blue
#> 4       2  yes blue
#> 5   apple <NA> blue
#> 6       4  yes  red
#> 7       1   no  red
#> 8  banana <NA> blue
#> 9       6  yes blue
#> 10      3  yes blue
```

Comment: Nice answer. This also works if there are multiple intervening rows between "apple" and "banana".

Answer (score 2):

Using `row_number` function from `dplyr` package

```
#reproducing example
df <- data.frame(a = c("5","6","7","2","apple","4","1","banana","6","3"), b = c("yes","no","no","yes","NA","yes","no","NA","yes","yes"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$c <- "blue"
lim1 <- which(df$a == "apple")
lim2 <- which(df$a == "banana")
```

**Method 1 :**

```
df$c[lim1:lim2] <- "red"
```

**Method 2 :**

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(c = ifelse(row_number(a) %in% lim1:lim2, "blue", "red"))
```

Comment: I couldn't get the OP's desired output when I used your method. May I know which version of `dplyr` are you using? The code `mutate(c = ifelse(row_number() %in% (lim1 + 1):(lim2 - 1), "red", "blue"))` works for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot @HNSKD :), my `dplyr` version is 0.4.3 though

Answer (score 1):

We can get the positions programmatically and then do the assign

```
i1 <- Reduce(`:`, which(is.na(df1$b))+ c(1, -1))
df1$c <- 'blue'
df1$c[i1] <- 'red'
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c("5", "6", "7", "2", "apple", "4", "1", "banana", 
"6", "3"), b = c("yes", "no", "no", "yes", NA, "yes", "no", NA, 
"yes", "yes")), .Names = c("a", "b"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

The dplyr package offers a `row_number()` function that can be used in conjunction with `mutate` and `ifelse` to assign values to specific row positions:

```
library(dplyr)
df = df %>% mutate(c=ifelse(row_number(a) %in% c(6,7),"red","blue"))
```

Answer (score 0):

with mutate and dplyr:

```
df %>% mutate(c = ifelse(row_number() %>% between(match("apple",a)+0.1,match("banana",a)-0.1),"red","blue"))
```

with base:

```
df <- transform(df,c = ifelse(1:nrow(df) > match("apple",a) & (1:nrow(df) < match("banana",a) ),"red","blue"))
```